# MVC: Editor for a list of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to do something similar to what is explained [in this question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1905215.aspx?EditorFor%20and%20an%20IEnumerable%20List%20): I want to edit a list of data.

The difference is that the base is not a list.

(I'm using VS 2013, so it is not old stuff.)

My view model:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    // ... other properties for editing ...

    // The list property
    public List<SampleListItemViewModel> ItemList { get; set; }
}

public class SampleListItemViewModel
{
    // For display only. It has an ID field to identify the row.
    public MyEntity Item { get; set; }

    // I want to modify this!
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

My attempted View:

```
@model My.Namespace.SampleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <!-- ... normal editing, MVC generated ... -->

    <!-- BEGIN LIST EDIT -->

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Is Applicable
            </th>
            <!-- ... -->
        </tr>

        @foreach (var doc in Model.ItemList)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => doc.Document.CRMDocumentId)

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => doc.IsChecked)
                    <!-- @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => doc.IsChecked) -->
                </td>
                <!-- ... other non-editable display fields, e.g. name ... -->
            </tr>
        }

    <!-- END LIST EDIT -->

    <!-- ... -->

}
```

When I create the view it shows everything as I want it, but when I click "Create" the item list is null.

**EDIT - More Info**

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        var item = // ...populate...
        // I confirmed that ItemList has values.
        return View(item);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(SampleViewModel item)
    {
        // This is null
        var list = item.ItemList;

        // ignoring all else for now

        return View(item);
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing when u click on "Create" link ?? Could you show us the code ??

Comment: Okay, can u try this - Make the constructor of **SampleViewModel** and initialize ItemList property like this - **ItemList = new List<SampleListItemViewModel>()** in the constructor and then check...

Comment: I don't do much in the controller yet, but I updated my question. I confirmed that ItemList has values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To bind complex objects, we need to provide an index for each item, rather than relying on the order of items. This ensures we can unambiguously match up the submitted properties with the correct object.

Replace the `foreach` loop with `for` loop:

```
@for (int i=0; i<Model.ItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.ItemList[i].Document.CRMDocumentId)

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.ItemList[i].IsChecked)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem.ItemList[i].IsChecked)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
```

**NOTE:**

> Note that the index must be an unbroken sequence of integers starting at 0 and increasing by 1 for each element

Also for every Property in the list which you don't want user to edit like for example **UserId etc** add an `@Html.HiddenFor(..)` for that property otherwise it will posted `null` to the server and  if hidden field created for them they will not be `NULL`.

For further details you can see [**HERE**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Also refer [**Model Binding with List**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: Thanks! Also, for every `@Html.DisplayFor(..)` in the list also add an `@Html.HiddenFor(..)` because then ASP will send the view-only data back to the server and it will not be NULL if the page reloads with validation errors.

Comment: @PeetBrits yes if you don't create hidden field for model object which you are not showing in view it will be posted null