# Strongly typed radiobutton list not posting back, shows empty when received from view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, strongly-typed-view

I'm trying to get a collection of radio buttons to postback. I'm able to display them on the form just fine, and when i submit i receive it on my controller but the list is empty, **what am I doing wrong here?**

**VIEW-MODEL**

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public class FederalClassificationViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

    public IList<FederalClassificationViewModel> federalClassificationsRadioViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
   //Retrieve all available radio buttons for tax information form
    var allTaxFederalClassList = _taxFederalRepo.GetAllTaxFederalClassesList();

    foreach (var federalClass in allTaxFederalClassList)
    {
        ProfileViewModel.FederalClassificationViewModel federalClassVM = new ProfileViewModel.FederalClassificationViewModel();

        federalClassVM.IsSelected = false;
        federalClassVM.Name       = federalClass.Name;
        federalClassVM.Id         = federalClass.id;

        model.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel.Add(federalClassVM);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@foreach(var radio in Model.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(p=>p.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel, radio) @radio.Name
}
```

---

**Updated with new Results**

```
@for(int i=0; i<Model.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(p=>p.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel[i].IsSelected, Model.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel[i].Id) @Model.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel[i].Name
}
```

**RESULTS**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC: Editor for a list of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533985/mvc-editor-for-a-list-of-data)

Comment: duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533985/mvc-editor-for-a-list-of-data

Comment: My question is not the same as that question you posted, I don't see the use of the Helper anywhere (RadioButtonFor)... Btw, both of your comments have the exact same link.

Comment: change your foreach to for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

Change your view model like:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{

    public class FederalClassificationViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

    public int SelectedClass {get;set;}
    public IList<FederalClassificationViewModel> federalClassificationsRadioViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Change your `foreach` to `for` loop:

```
    @for(int i=0; i<Model.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(p=>p.
SelectedClass,Model.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel[i].Id) @Model.federalClassificationsRadioViewModel[i].Name
    }
```

You need to understand Model binding of `List`, `Collection` and `Arrays`, you can see [**details here**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)